# Magento automatic redirect to cms page if not clicked?

Tags: magento, redirect, content-management-system

i was wondering if it was possible to make your front page automatic redirect to another CMS page if nothing was clicked on?

For example, on my front page on www.trendee.dk you have to choose your language before continuing to the store, but i want it to automatically redirect to the store, if nothing is clicked.

Comment: Do you want to do this after a certain time has elapsed?

Comment: Yes, so if nothing is clicked for, lets say 10 seconds, it automatically redirects to another cms page.

Comment: On a separate note - that site has way too much whitespace in the middle for us visitors with wide screen - I'm on a 2560px wide screen and it's 90% whitespace on product pages!

Comment: I'm not so technical, what does it mean that it's 90% whitespace?
Should i make the pictures + text bigger? :-)

Comment: Okay, I'm on my laptop now so this is at 1920x1080, but there's still a lot of white space, but here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/QpekfMB.png

Comment: Thank you, i'm fixing that right away ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple javascript redirect on a timeout?

E.g.:

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.assign("http://trendee.dk/home?___store=english");
}, 1000*10); // redirects to another url after ten seconds.
```

If you want to cancel the redirect, you can just clear the timeout:

```
clearTimeout(timeout);
```

Comment: Anywhere on the home page inside ```<script> tags </script>```. Edit: If you don't know how to do that, just google 'How to add javascript snippet to CMS page in Magento'. It looks like the CMS page in question would be your cms-firstpage

Comment: Sorry, I'd accidentally put 10 minutes instead of 10 seconds, but I also can't see the code anywhere on the landing page? That code should work fine (although you have same origin policy, so I can't test directly) see: http://jsfiddle.net/Manticorp/as1awgn1/2/

Comment: Just tested on the landing page for your site using the browser console - seems to work fine for me.

Comment: I'm surely doing something wrong, but i've written the code under the page and design>Layout Update XML

Is that wrong?